# How to randomly pick a node at a position?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have five different colored circles, each called in the same function but with different physicsBodies and names. I would like them all to move upwards from the bottom of the screen with only one node on the screen at a time from one set position (i.e, CGPointMake(100, -500)) Like after a randomly colored node is generated, after 4 seconds a different randomly picked one will appear?

Is there a way to keep all of them individually identified and do this?

Code:

```
      func circles() {

     let sprites = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle1")
       sprites.position = CGPointMake(45, -200)

        sprites.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
        sprites.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        sprites.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        sprites.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue
        sprites.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy.rawValue | BodyType.other.rawValue | BodyType.seven.rawValue | BodyType.nine.rawValue | BodyType.five.rawValue

        sprites.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45)
        all.addChild(sprites)
        let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle2")
        sprite2.position = CGPointMake(60, -750)
        sprite2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
        sprite2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.eight.rawValue
        sprite2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.nine.rawValue | BodyType.other.rawValue | BodyType.five.rawValue | BodyType.enemy.rawValue | BodyType.seven.rawValue
        sprite2.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        sprite2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        sprite2.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45)
         addChild(sprite2)
        let sprite3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle3")
        sprite3.position = CGPointMake(100, -1200)
        sprite3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
        sprite3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.six.rawValue
        sprite3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.seven.rawValue | BodyType.other.rawValue | BodyType.five.rawValue | BodyType.enemy.rawValue | BodyType.nine.rawValue
        sprite3.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        sprite3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        sprite3.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45)
        addChild(sprite3)
        let sprite4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle4")
        sprite4.position = CGPointMake(150, -1400)
        sprite4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
        sprite4.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ground.rawValue
        sprite4.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.other.rawValue | BodyType.player.rawValue | BodyType.five.rawValue | BodyType.enemy.rawValue | BodyType.seven.rawValue
        sprite4.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        sprite4.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        sprite4.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45)
        addChild(sprite4)
        let sprite5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle5")
        sprite5.position = CGPointMake(200, -850)
        sprite5.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
        sprite5.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ya.rawValue
        sprite5.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.five.rawValue | BodyType.player.rawValue | BodyType.other.rawValue | BodyType.seven.rawValue | BodyType.nine.rawValue


        sprite5.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        sprite5.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        sprite5.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45)
        addChild(sprite5)
          }
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name property of `SKNode`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/name):

> Used to assign a name to a node for later reference. When choosing a
>   name for a node, you should decide whether each node gets a unique
>   name or whether some nodes will share a common name. If you give the
>   node a unique name, you can find the node later by calling the
>   childNodeWithName: method. If a name is shared by multiple nodes, the
>   name usually means that these are all a similar object type in your
>   game. In this case, you can iterate over those objects by calling the
>   enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock: method.

Comment: Does this work when giving nodes their own physics bodies as well? Thats really what I'm looking for.